# Error log showing "File does not exist", how to disable?

Tags: logging

We are running Centos 6.5 with Plesk, in the `/var/www/vhosts/{domain}/log` folder we have the access log and the error log files.

When I open the error log file (`error_log`) I see thousands of errors with:

```
 [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: {file path}
```

These are all images, as the site runs a very large vBulletin some plugins and template files are searching for old files. Instead of fixing those we first want to clean up the error logs with these low-level errors to see if there are errors with priority. (The site has just been migrated to a new server). Is there a way of changing the error log level or something to only log errors created by PHP files etc.?

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the [`ErrorLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#errorlog):

> It is not possible to customize the error log by adding or removing information.

But that is only if you use the ErrorLog directive. If you set up a custom log you can use [conditional logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog) to exclude or include specific requests:

```
# Mark requests for the robots.txt file
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/robots\.txt$" dontlog
# Log what remains
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```

The better option might be to set a rewrite rule that redirects broken image to a stock image e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /images/broken-link.jng [L]
```